# How to set default time in vue2-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I am using "vue2-datepicker" plugin in my vue.js project, when i tried set default time in `mounted()` or set it in `data()` not show

```
<template>
    <date-picker v-model="checkinTime" :time-picker-options="{start: '08:00',step: '00:30',end: '20:00',}" format="hh:mm" type="time" placeholder="Time"></date-picker>
</template>

<script>
    data(){
        return{
            checkinTime:'12:20',
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or

```
mounted(){
    this.checkinTime = '12:20'
}
```

Or, from api like :

```
 data(){
     return{
         checkinTime:'',
         listJCP:[],
     }
 }

async mounted(){
    this.listJCP = await getJCPList(this.$route.params.merchandiser_id,this.filter_Jcp_Obj)
    this.checkinTime = moment(this.listJCP.get_duration_of_jcp.checkIn_time).format('hh:mm')
}
```

Nothing of this appears

Comment: Seems like you have a typo '<templete>' should be '<template>', and make sure to have a root element, (such as putting your component between divs, <template><div><component/></div></template> ), otherwise i cant see a problem with the code

Comment: I know that , but this is a part of project like a simple only

Comment: Can you create a codepen and recreate your issue so its easier for others to debug?

Comment: @MostafaAhmed Whilst you have set type="time" I think you may also need to set the value-type which is the data type of the binding value: value-type="time"

Comment: @Bryan I've tried it, but the same result

Comment: @procoib yes of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replace `v-model` to `:value`

```
<template>
    <date-picker v-model="checkinTime" :time-picker-options="{start: '08:00',step: '00:30',end: '20:00',}" format="hh:mm" type="time" placeholder="Time"></date-picker>{{checkinTime}}
</template>

<script>
    data(){
        return{
            checkinTime:'05:06',
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now it work correctly 
[image]